# Retrieving data from swapi external api in nextjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, rest

I've got a list of names fetch from a external API called SWAPI and I would like to get a single detail character. I'got to connect the data and the list is working perfectly but when I click and sends me to the single detail character, doesn't recognise which character id, it says undefined. I can get the page with the character but not with the corresponding id.

```
       <ul>
        {data.results.map((result) => (
          <div key={result.episode_id} className="column">
            <Link
              href={`/character/?id=http://${result.id}`}
            >
                <h4 className="card-title">
                  <a>{result.name}</a>
                </h4>
          </Link>
          </div>
        ))}
        </ul>

  export async function getServerSideProps() {
    const res = await fetch(`https://swapi.dev/api/people/`)
    const data = await res.json()
  
    return { props : {data} }
 }
```

I tried to route as a Link with href to send me to the single character with the ${result.id} to fetch only the id but it doesn't like the solution.
It sends me to the page character but doesn't recognise the id, it says undefined.

Comment: 1) it looks like the character 'id' already contains the `https://` part for other things in that API, so you shouldn't copy it. 2) if you are embedding special characters in urls (like youre with ?id=url..), you should 'query string escape' the values.

Comment: that's the closer I've got. I tried just the id: or character/id: or character/result.id or just result.id or just quering the id. http://localhost:3000/character?id=undefined

Comment: Do you get the expected response from the `https://swapi.dev/api/people/` endpoint? If you log `data` to the console, do you see the expected values for the `result.id` fields?